# Capture post content before page renders

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I'm trying to mesh Mustache Templating Engine with WordPress. So far, I have been very successful using the_content as a filter to parse my template tags e.g. `{{ something }}`.

However, if let’s say, a developer hardcodes the template tags directly into the page template e.g. loop-page, the_content doesn’t capture the hardcoded tags.

Is there a filter that will allow me to capture the content of the whole page template including the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not concatenate the entire page into a string before printing it which is what would have to happen to "capture" the whole page template. Much of the page `echo`s as it occurs-- think about template tags like `the_content` and `the_title` which don't return strings. The just `echo` them.

You'd have to use output buffering to do this. That is pretty easy if you are writing the template-- `ob_start` at the beginning or `header.php` and `ob_get_contents` (or `ob_get_clean`) at the end of `footer.php`. But there are no hooks specifically at those locations. You should be able to capture most of the page with `ob_start` on a `wp_head` filter and `ob_get_contents` on a `wp_footer` filters. I'd have to play with things to dial it in. There may be a slightly better hook for `ob_start`. I doubt there is a better one for `ob_get_contents`.

Comment: Genius genius genius. I should have thought of this. Hooked it up in just a few line.